# Pull up bar mounted on a plank that's attached to a stud. How is this safer?

Tags: mounting, studs, fastener

[The BEST Garage Gym Pull Up Bar for Your Money | Garage Gym Project Part 4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fv_bA8aVmjs)

In the above video, the guy mounted the pull up bar on a 1" pine board, that is attached to a stud (possibly a 2 by 4). He seemed to have drilled the pull-up bar nail all the way into the board and then a little into the stud. I am trying to understand how this adds more reinforcement.

Also, I need to know if having an additional wooden board is necessary?

Comment: Where a board becomes extra important is if the board can reach two studs but the pullup bar can only get directly into one. Happens all the time with TV mounts.

Comment: In this case, both the brackets are on studs.

Comment: Which is a good design. And in which case Cliff's answer (which I already upvoted) is indeed the reason. If you ever decide to remove the brackets, the pine board will mean you just need to patch a couple of tiny holes instead of much larger chunks of drywall.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 1" pine boards are only used to keep the steel brackets from digging into the drywall. They provide no strength at all. The 5" screws go about 2.5" into the studs. So, you would only need the pine boards (or similar) if you have drywall or other soft material over the studs.

Comment: But the pine board may end up digging into the drywall as well. How is one better than the other?

Comment: In this case it doesn't appear to make a ton of sense. The times it might make sense is if there are more screws in the middle of the board.

Comment: Larger surface area distributes force better and digs in less.

Comment: @keshlam Pine also holds up much better against shock and movement compared to drywall, so not only is the pine distributing the force, it is also preventing the steel bars from rubbing off the drywall. If you put the bars directly onto the drywall, the drywall between the stud and bars will not handle the weight very well, and eventually crumble. Note that the pull-up bars take MOVING weight of 100s of lbs. It's not a cabinet where it is static. There will be motion, and that motion will rub the drywall off.